# How to Upload images in the Admin Domain, and Save them in images folder in another domain (blog)?

Tags: php, server, uploading

Here is my problem, I have two domain names, lets say, x.com (users domain) and y.com (admin domain). They are using the same database.

I upload everything from the admin website and save in the common database, where the other site, x.com is fetching from.

My problem comes when am uploading images to be used by x.com Here is what I want to do, I want to upload images in the admin website, save the image in the images folder in the other site. and save the link to the database. The link is saving correctly but the image is not uploaded.

Is what am trying to do possible? And if yes, how can I achieve that?
Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand it right, you want to mirror images folder from x.com to y.com?

Comment: No. What am looking for is to store images in the images folder in x.com when I upload them from y.com, which is the admin site, and store link to the database. The link is inserted correctly  but i have no idea how to save the images.

Comment: are those 2 domain under the same server or in different server?

Comment: They are in the same server